# How can I wait for the image to load in my new window before printing via child.print()?

Tags: javascript, printing, popup, parent-child, onload

```
    $("#print").on('click', function () {
        var child = window.open("image.jpg", "_blank", "location=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,fullscreen=1,menubar=0");
        //any way to know/wait for image to load?
        child.print();
    });
```

Any way for my parent window to know that the child window has completed loading the image prior to calling .print()? If they were trigger happy they would end up printing a blank page.

I've tried both:

```
child.attachEvent("onload", function () { child.print(); });
```

and

```
child.attachEvent("DOMContentLoaded", function () { child.print(); });
//(found this online, apparently it's Firefox only, still didn't work)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to need to create a page, i.e. `print.html` and add this script to it:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script>
(function( w, d ) {
    var paramsHash = {},
        img = new Image(); 

    (function() {
        var qs = w.location.href.split( '?' )[ 1 ],
            items = [],
            l = 0,
            i = 0,
            param;
        if( qs && qs.indexOf( '&' ) ) {
            items = qs.split( '&' );
        } else {
            items = [ qs ];
        }
        l = items.length;
        for( ; i < l; i++ ) {
            param = items[i].split( '=' );
            paramsHash[ param[ 0 ] ] = param[ 1 ];
        }
    })();
    console.log(paramsHash);
    img.src = paramsHash.img;
    //after the image is loaded, call this function
    img.onload = function() {
        window.print();        
    };
    d.body.appendChild( img );

})( window, document );
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then use it like so:

```
$("#print").on('click', function () {
    window.open("print.html?img=image.jpg", "_blank", "location=0,toolbar=0,scrollbars=1,fullscreen=1,menubar=0");
    });
```